# Make Powerpoint "Timer" in Presentation Mode more prominent

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have a presentation which I will show on a projector with my laptop screen in "Presentation Mode", showing the current slide, but also other things, like the next slide. In addition, it has a timer, but it is *tiny* and unobtrusive:

[image: Powerpoint Presentation Mode]

Is there a way to make this timer:

- A lot bigger
- Count down from a specific timespan
- Color (e.g. yellow, then red) as you approach the alotted time

So that it is actually *obtrusive* (and thus more helpful)?

PS. I have [posted on UserVoice](https://powerpoint.uservoice.com/forums/270149-powerpoint-online/suggestions/33906184-options-to-make-timer-in-presentation-mode-more-pr) a suggestion to add this feature to PowerPoint, but will leave my question here too because I'm interested in hearing workarounds achieving something similar.

Comment: It is by design in PowerPoint. Maybe you can submit a feedback to Microsoft. https://powerpoint.uservoice.com

Comment: @WinniL Good idea, [posted it on UserVoice](https://powerpoint.uservoice.com/forums/270149-powerpoint-online/suggestions/33906184-options-to-make-timer-in-presentation-mode-more-pr).